# Type definitions with open unions

Tags: types, ocaml, variant

1) I have an open union defined as follows:

```
type 'a choice = [> `One | `Other ] as 'a
```

I then try to define a type choice_list:

```
type choice_list = choice list
```

which does not work. How does one define types where one or more of the components are open unions?

2) If instead I forgo creating the `choice_list` type, and just use a `choice list`, when I try writing an interface/signature statement using a choice list,

```
val choice_handler : choice list -> int
```

the compiler complains that `` type 'a choice = 'a constraint 'a = [> `One | `Other ] is not included in type infection_state. They have different arities ``.

My question is, how does one write the type declaration of choice list in the interface/signature.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler is trying to tell you that `choice` is a parameterized type.  At the type level, it has an arity of 1.  In other words, you need to supply one type parameter.  You have constrained the parameter to be a subtype of `` [`One|`Other] ``, but other than that it can be any type:

```
# ([`One; `Third] : 'a choice list);;
- : [> `One | `Other | `Third ] choice list = [`One; `Third]
```

If you want to define a list of choices, the extra type has to come from somewhere.  I.e., it has to be a parameter to the new type:

```
# type 'a choice_list = 'a choice list;;
type 'a choice_list = 'a choice list constraint 'a = [> `One | `Other ]
```

(These sorts of constructions get tricky pretty fast, in my experience.)